# addEventListner working only at app creation

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs

For some reason my eventHandling code stopped working.
I was working on some functions to handle the indexedDB stuff, when i went back to work on the interface, i noticed that the eventHandlers only worked at app creation, even when i didnt performed any action on them, they just go off.
Heres my default.js

```
(function () {
"use strict";

WinJS.Binding.optimizeBindingReferences = true;

var app = WinJS.Application;
var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
var _swAlarm;

app.onactivated = function (args) {
    if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
        if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !== activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {

        } else {

        }
        args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll());
    }
};

app.oncheckpoint = function (args) {

};

function testSelection(value) {
    console.log("from event listner "+value)
}

function getDomElements() {
    _swAlarm = document.getElementById("swAlarm");
}

function registerHandlers() {
    _swAlarm.addEventListener("onchange", console.log("ola"));
}


app.onready = function () {
    getDomElements();
    registerHandlers();
}

app.start();
```

And this is my default.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>MyApp</title>

    <!-- WinJS references -->
    <link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/ui.js"></script>

    <!-- my references -->
    <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/js/default.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/database.js"></script>

    <!-- jquery references -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2-win8-1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/visualize.jQuery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> jQuery.isUnsafe = true;</script>
    <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="settings">
            <h2 id="lAlarm">Alarm</h2>
            <div id="swAlarm" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ToggleSwitch" ></div>
            <input id="iMaxval" type="number">
            <input id="iMinval" type="number">
            <button id="bSave">Save</button>

        </div>

        <div id="graph">
            <h2 id="hGraph" class="graph">Graph</h2>
        </div>

        <div id="stats">
            <h2 id="hStats" class="stats">Stats</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where's the closing of `(function () {` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run this code:

`_swAlarm.addEventListener("onchange", console.log("ola"));`

you are:

1. running `console.log("ola")`
2. affecting the result as a callback for the event onchange of _swAlarm.

This is wrong on many levels.

1. `console.log("ola")` does not return a call back. I think I understand what you meant, and the correct code could be: `function() { console.log("ola"); }`
2. When using `addEventListener` you have to use [dom lexique](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html) with event denomination. In your case, `onchange` needs to be instead `change`. If you had to affect this event directly in html, you indeed would have to use `onchange="console.log("ola");"`. But not with `addEventListener`.

The final result is:

`_swAlarm.addEventListener("change", function() { console.log("ola"); }, false);`

As for why was it working on app creation, I think it is simply because on app creation `console.log("ola")` was called right away at event affectation, but since no event was actually affected later on you would not get any result for the `onchange` event.

---

On a side note, and since I guess you're sort of migrating from "old" syntaxis (onchange... etc.) to the `addEventListener` api, I'll add an important difference between the 2 modes: when an event is executed the old way, `this` referers to `window`. But affecting the callback through `addEventListener` makes the `domElement` itself (`_swAlarm` in your case) be the target of `this` during the callback execution.

Comment: I added the link to dom if you want to see the event names. Basically it is the same but without the "on" for I think almost all event